# HERE Routing API v8: How to add waypoint labels?

Tags: here-api, here-routing

In v7, HERE allowed waypoints to be sent with a "userLabel" so that when you get the navigation instructions, they will say "Now arriving at Your House" rather than "Now arriving at destination".
In v8, there seems to be no way to send a "userLabel" with the via (waypoint). Is there any way to customize the instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the custom label identifying waypoints like in V7 is missing and was not yet migrated to v8.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I got confirmation from HERE saying this is not implemented in v8 and it sounded like they do not intend to do so.